# Can I get multiple hospital indemnity plans (e.g. Aflac and such)?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, medical-bill

Is it possible to get multiple hospital indemnity plans from different companies such as Aflac and Metlife? If I were to get one by myself, can I cancel any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Health insurance pays for specific medical services after deductible or co-payment amounts are satisfied.

A hospital indemnity covers the overall event, namely hospitalization.  It's usually a per diem amount  (paid daily or in a lump sum) of a set amount by the insurer but policy terms can vary.  Some insurance companies offer tiers of coverage ($100 a day, $200 a day, etc.).  More robust plans may cover  ambulance trips, surgery, etc.

Yes, you can get multiple hospital indemnity plans from different companies.  I've owned two for many years.  It's not a long term contract.  You are free to cancel at any time.